# Why do i keep getting this error for a script that extracts SSO accounts and their information and save it into a csv file on my local

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, single-sign-on, aws-organizations

I have created the following script in Python that uses "instance-arn" and my CLI cred to extract SSO accounts and their information and save them onto a csv file in my local.

I keep on getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\<username> & "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" c:/Users/<username>/Downloads/sso_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<username>\Downloads\sso_script.py", line 22, in <module>
    permission_sets = sso_client.list_permission_sets_provisioned_to_account(AccountId=account_id)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 875, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'Organizations' object has no attribute 'list_permission_sets_provisioned_to_account'
```

Here is my code:

```
import boto3

# Get the instance ARN from the user.
instance_arn = ''

# Create a Boto3 client for AWS SSO.
sso_client = boto3.client("organizations")

# Get a list of all accounts in the organization.
accounts = sso_client.list_accounts()

# Create a list to store the account information.
account_info = []

# Iterate over the accounts.
for account in accounts["Accounts"]:

    # Get the account ID.
    account_id = account["Id"]

    # Get a list of all permission sets provisioned to the account.
    permission_sets = sso_client.list_permission_sets_provisioned_to_account(AccountId=account_id)

    # Create a list to store the permission set information.
    permission_set_info = []

    # Iterate over the permission sets.
    for permission_set in permission_sets["PermissionSets"]:

        # Get the permission set name.
        permission_set_name = permission_set["Name"]

        # Get a list of all account assignments for the permission set.
        account_assignments = sso_client.list_account_assignments(PermissionSetArn=permission_set["Arn"])

        # Create a list to store the account assignment information.
        account_assignment_info = []

        # Iterate over the account assignments.
        for account_assignment in account_assignments["AccountAssignments"]:

            # Get the username.
            username = account_assignment["UserName"]

            # Add the account information to the list.
            account_info.append({
                "AccountId": account_id,
                "Username": username,
                "PermissionSetName": permission_set_name
            })

# Write the account information to a CSV file.
with open("sso_accounts.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["AccountId", "Username", "PermissionSetName"])
    writer.writerows(account_info)

print("Done!")
```

I even tried using sso-admin instead of organizations as my sso_client but it gave the same error of no attribute. Can someone help me with this?

I expect the data into my csv file.

Answer (score 0):

[list_permission_sets_provisioned_to_account](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso-admin/client/list_permission_sets_provisioned_to_account.html) is in `sso-admin`, not in `organizations`. So you have to use `sso-admin` client:

```
sso_admin_client = boto3.client("sso-admin")
```

Comment: raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'SSOAdmin' object has no attribute 'list_accounts'

getting this error when using SSOAdmin

Comment: @shubh You need two clinets. One for `organizations` and one for `sso-admin`.